# Display Foundation datepicker inline? without clicking the textbox?

Tags: datepicker, zurb-foundation

How to show the foundation datepicker inline? just want to show the calander on load without clinking the textbox?

Comment: What does your code look like e.g. html, jquery, css, etc.? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i'm using html, css/scss(foundation), jquery

Comment: Would you be able to create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) example of what you've done so far?